# Retrieving Android phone's identifiers

Tags: android, spoofing, identification

I will be publishing a fingerprinting app that shows its user how much access to their Android phone's identifiers it has. I haven't started writing it because I need to understand how can any Android phone be identified by using ***only*** its hardware as IMEI and software as Google Ads ID identifier. Even CPU model is considered an identifier. It must not use other identifiers as Internet Protocol addresses or user-generated data as email addresses. Therefore I have the following questions:

1. What identifiers can Android theoretically provide access to any app that requests them?
2. Which of them need user-granted access permission before the app reads the identifiers? Which of them don't? For example any app can retrieve phone model name without being explicitly given access to it by phone's user. But the request to read and write device storage be approved by user explicitly via Android GUI.
3. How can I know how a specific Android version impacts whether my app will be able to read the ID? For example, starting from Android 10 no app can read IMEI even if it possesses READ_PHONE_STATE permission as I read it from another SE question [Uniquely identify each mobile phone of Android 10 / 9 and below](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/224487/uniquely-identify-each-mobile-phone-of-android-10-9-and-below)
4. How can my app's user consciously evade app's access to any of these IDs? Can they spoof all of them or just opt-out of revealing them?

Comment: That sounds a lot like a university assignment. Is it?

Comment: MAC address is also not visible to non-system apps anymore. You can only see advertising ID and IP Address.

Comment: Cross-posted from Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249523/44325

Comment: @Theonewhotests maybe it does, but I see a tendency that many university assignments tend to be too degenerate and boring :)